# Microchip c18 placing rom data in idata

Tags: c, microchip

I have a project that was released as a product, last code update about 4 years ago. Compiled with MicroChip C18 (I also have XC18 available but that's another story). I am attempting to get it to recompile to the same working executable preparatory to making some upgrades. I have a large fixed data structure, declared with the rom keyword, but C18 keeps trying to put it in iData, where it obviously cannot fit. I have checked for bogus redefines of the rom keyword, and the compiler manual is very clear that this should be placed in rom only, vs. initialized data which would have space allocated in ram, with initialization values in rom. I've been tearing my hair out on this one for a couple weeks now. Any hints welcome!

I have tried #undef ROM (which is in fact defined as rom) and redefining it locally, as well as various combinations of rom and const. Also played with memory models; this application clearly requires large model for both program and data.

Comment: Why not post the code that demos the problem, a [mcve]?

Comment: "I am attempting to get it to recompile to the same working executable" Welcome to SO. That sounds as if you did not yet make the changes you need to. Why do you get different results now? Do you use the same tools (same version) and project configuration files as 4 years ago? Keeping a copy of all the relevant tools is as important as keeping the source files.

Comment: You're preaching to the choir about saving all the files and tools. Yes, same tools. I thought I was saving all the files as well, didn't realize how many file Mchip TCPIP stack was hiding from me (they aren't any more). And yes, I'm just trying to get a recompile before making changes. The offending line is in mpfsimg2.c, which is automatically generated by their HTML compiler for the TCPIP stack. Here's the actual line; the data in DATACHUNK000000 etc. is irrelevant.

Comment: rom const BYTE  MPFS_Start [] = {DATACHUNK000000, DATACHUNK000001, DATACHUNK000002, DATACHUNK000003, DATACHUNK000004, DATACHUNK000005, DATACHUNK000006, DATACHUNK000007, DATACHUNK000008, DATACHUNK000009, DATACHUNK00000a, DATACHUNK00000b, DATACHUNK00000c, DATACHUNK00000d, DATACHUNK00000e, DATACHUNK00000f, DATACHUNK000010, DATACHUNK000011};

Comment: I have tried just rom, just const, rom const, and even tried adding static. No matter, the compiler places it in idata rather than in romdata, thus requiring some 18K in RAM - of which the 97J60 has only 3808 bytes. No kidding that it doesn't fit. Now, how do I beat the compiler into submission to put the struct in ROM like the TCPIP stack was designed?

Sorry for the tone, this is but one of many circular aggravations today....

Comment: Ash now one more aggravation, that it wouldn't post because it was too long. At least it allowed me to break it into chunks and post.